# How to call static library function in a C++ class?

Tags: c++, static, static-functions

I have class whose header file is defined as:

```
namespace mip {
    class CustomStatic {
        public:
            static const char* GetVersion();
    };
}
```

And class file is defined as:

```
#include "CustomStatic.h"

namespace mip {
    static const char* GetVersion() {
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

I am accessing this static function from my main class

```
#include "CustomStatic.h"

#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using mip::CustomStatic;

int main() {
    const char *msg = mip::CustomStatic::GetVersion();
    cout << "Version " << msg << "\n";
}
```

When I try to compile it using-

```
g++ -std=c++11 -I CustomStatic.h  MainApp.cpp CustomStatic.cpp
```

I am getting error as:

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>   "mip::CustomStatic::GetVersion()", referenced from:
>         _main in MainApp-feb286.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code
>   1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: define it as `const char* CustomStatic::GetVersion()`. Please read some C++ introductory book.

Comment: @songyuanyao no `static` needed here

Comment: You declare the function `mip::CustomStatic::GetVersion`, but define `mip::GetVersion`.

Comment: And also mismatch between declaration and definition, so that's the usual undefined reference duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your static function is not properly implemented in the cpp file...

you need to do something like

```
//.h
namespace mip
{
    class CustomStatic
    {
         public:
            static const char* GetVersion();
    };
}


//.cpp -> note that no static keyword is required...
namespace mip
{
    const char* CustomStatic::GetVersion()
    {
        return "hello";
    }
}

//use
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    const char* msg{mip::CustomStatic::GetVersion()};
    cout << "Version " << msg << "\n";
}
```